# Find all descendants deeply of tree structure from flat data

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a flat data that represent the hierarchical relationship as below:

```
ID  Name    PID
0   A       NULL
1   B       0
2   C       0
4   D       1
5   E       1
6   F       4
3   G       0
```

This table represents the 'data table', where PID indicates the parent element. 
For example, in the first row we see that A has PID null whereas B has PID 0, which means that B’s parent is A, because 0 is the ID of A, and A is the root element, because it does not have a PID. Similarly, C has parent A because C too has PID 0, and 0 is the ID of A.

I create a class DataTable to represent the above table. I also implement the method processDataTable

```
public Map<String, List<String>> processDataTable()
```

The returned map uses element as keys, and holds collections of descendantnodes as values. For example, the first item in the map corresponds to element A, which has many descendants, whereas element C has no descendant. The order of members in the output is not important.

```
public static void main(String...arg) {

     DataTable dt = newDataTable();

     dt.addRow(0, "A", null);
     dt.addRow(1, "B", 0);
     dt.addRow(2, "C", 0);
     dt.addRow(4, "D", 1);
     dt.addRow(5, "E", 1);
     dt.addRow(6, "F", 4);
     dt.addRow(3, "G", 0);

     System.out.println("Output:");
     System.out.println(dt.processDataTable());
 }

Output:
{D=[F], A=[B, C, G, D, E, F], B=[D, E, F]}
or
{D=[F], E=null, F=null, G=null, A=[B, C, G, D, E, F], B=[D, E, F], C=null}
```

Below is my implementation of DataTable:

```
public class DataTable {

    private List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Integer, Integer> indexes = new HashMap<>();
    private static final int PROCESSORS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    /**
     * Add new record into DataTable.
     * 
     * @param id
     * @param name
     * @param parentId
     */
    public void addRow(Integer id, String name, Integer parentId) {
        if (indexes.get(id) == null) {
            Record rec = new Record(id, name, parentId);
            records.add(rec);
            indexes.put(id, records.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public List<Record> getRecords() {
       return records;
    }

    /**
     * Process DataTable and return a Map of all keys and its children. The
     * main algorithm here is to divide big record set into multiple parts, compute
     * on multi threads and then merge all result together.
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Map<String, List<String>> processDataTable() {
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
       int size = size();

       // Step 1: Link all nodes together
       invokeOnewayTask(new LinkRecordTask(this, 0, size));

       Map<String, List<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

       // Step 2: Get result
       invokeOnewayTask(new BuildChildrenMapTask(this, 0, size, map));

       long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

       System.out.println("Total elapsed time: " + elapsedTime + " ms");

       return map;
    }

    /**
     * Invoke given task one way and measure the time to execute.
     * 
     * @param task
     */
    private void invokeOnewayTask(ForkJoinTask<?> task) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(PROCESSORS);
        pool.invoke(task);
        long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println(task.getClass().getSimpleName() + ":" + elapsedTime + " ms");
    }

    /**
     * Find record by id.
     * 
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    public Record getRecordById(Integer id) {
        Integer pos = indexes.get(id);
        if (pos != null) {
            return records.get(pos);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Find record by row number.
     * 
     * @param rownum
     * @return
     */
    public Record getRecordByRowNumber(Integer rownum) {
       return (rownum < 0 || rownum > records.size() - 1) ? null:records.get(rownum);
    }

    public int size() {
       return records.size();
    }

    /**
     * A task link between nodes
     */
    private static class LinkRecordTask extends RecursiveAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DataTable dt;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int limit = 100;

    public LinkRecordTask(DataTable dt, int start, int end) {
        this.dt = dt;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if ((end - start) < limit) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            Record r = dt.records.get(i);
            Record parent = dt.getRecordById(r.parentId);
            r.parent = parent;
            if(parent != null) {
               parent.children.add(r);
            }
        }
        } else {
           int mid = (start + end) / 2;
           LinkRecordTask left = new LinkRecordTask(dt, start, mid);
           LinkRecordTask right = new LinkRecordTask(dt, mid, end);
           left.fork();
           right.fork();
           left.join();
           right.join();
        }
    }

    }

    /**
     * Build Map<String, List<String>> result from given DataTable.
     */
    private static class BuildChildrenMapTask extends RecursiveAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private DataTable dt;
        private int start;
        private int end;
        private int limit = 100;
        private Map<String, List<String>> map;

        public BuildChildrenMapTask(DataTable dt, int start, int end, Map<String, List<String>> map) {
            this.dt = dt;
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
            this.map = map;
        }

        @Override
        protected void compute() {
            if ((end - start) < limit) {
               computeDirectly();
            } else {
                int mid = (start + end) / 2;
                BuildChildrenMapTask left = new BuildChildrenMapTask(dt, start, mid, map);
                BuildChildrenMapTask right = new BuildChildrenMapTask(dt, mid, end, map);
                left.fork();
                right.fork();
                left.join();
                right.join();
           }
        }

        private void computeDirectly() {  
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                Record rec = dt.records.get(i);
                List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

                loadDeeplyChildNodes(rec, names);

                if(!names.isEmpty()) {
                    map.put(rec.name, names);
                }
            }
        }

        private void loadDeeplyChildNodes(Record r, List<String> names) {
             Collection<Record> children = r.children;
             for(Record rec:children) {
                if(!names.contains(rec.name)) {
                   names.add(rec.name);
                }
                loadDeeplyChildNodes(rec, names);
             }
        }

    }

}
```

My Record class:

```
/**
 * Represents a structure of a record in DataTable.
 */
public class Record {

    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public Integer parentId;
    public Record parent;
    public Collection<Record> children;

    public Record(Integer id, String name, Integer parentId) {
        this();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public Record() {
       children = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Record, Boolean>())
    }

    public Collection<Record> getChildren() {
       return children;
    }

    public Record getParent() {
       return parent;
    }

    public Integer getParentId() {
       return parentId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Record{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", parentId=" + parentId + '}';
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
       final int prime = 31;
       int result = 1;
       result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
       result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
       result = prime * result  + ((parentId == null) ? 0 : parentId.hashCode());
       return result;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Record)) {
        return false;
    }
    Record other = (Record) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null) {
        return false;
        }
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null) {
        return false;
        }
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (parentId == null) {
        if (other.parentId != null) {
        return false;
        }
    } else if (!parentId.equals(other.parentId)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }

}
```

My algorithm is:

```
    - Link all parent and child of each record
    - Build the map 

On each step I apply fork join to divide the dataset into smaller parts and run in parellel.
```

I don't know what's wrong with this implementation. Could anybody give me some advice? This implementation got OutOfmemory error on case Linear hierarchy 5K records (item 1 is the root and parent of item 2, item 2 is the parent of item 3, item 3 is the parent of item 4,... and so on). It got OutOfmemory because it call recursive method so many times.

What is the good algorithm for this issue or which data structure should I have to modify to make it better?

Comment: In LinkChildrenTask's compute(), why are you adding a node to each ancestor's children list? Is your intent to add every child and grandchild of a node to that node's list of children to know quickly if it's somewhere in its subtree? That can use an extremely large amount of memory. In your example, about 12.5 million references.

Comment: The first time I implement I only add directly children of each node, not all children. But in BuildChildrenMapTask it has to recursive so many times to find all nested children and it also fail too on that task. With this test case there are so many children of each node :( :( :(

Comment: This looks significantly different. Is it in loadDeeplyChildNodes() you're getting the error? This would make sense considering your root node will have a stack 5000 calls deep, the root's child will have a stack 4999 deep, etc.

Comment: It run too long and after that it throws error GC exceed limit or OutOfmemory exception. With this implementation it runs very slow :( :( :( :( and throws exception with this case too

Comment: The error: Exception in thread “main” java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Comment: Yes, well, if you run it under a debugger you should see that you have a lot of calls to loadDeeplyChildNodes() on the stack. With 5000 records and a termination criteria of 100 in a set for direct calculation, that would be 128 tasks, each with a set of ~78 records to go over, which would mean ~640000 calls in the worst case scenario (I'm sure someone will correct my math at some point). The recursive solution likely isn't a good one, especially since you're duplicating a lot of your work in each task.

Comment: Is there any better way to solve this issue? Could you give me some hint to improve the algorithm or the data structure?

Comment: Math is bad - 64 tasks * ~78 records, so about 160000 calls on the stack depending on timing. Still very bad. Recursion can be good for divide-and-conquer, but you're duplicating so much work that it's working against you. Why don't you traverse the tree in one thread to start with, collecting names as you go down, then adding them to each parent as you come back up the tree? The worst-case scenario in that case would be a number of calls equal to the number of nodes in the tree, if it's a linear hierarchy.

Comment: I also have another test case Random parent child, this case will have number of records up to 500K. If I run in one thread it will run too slow although in this case the number of children not so many

Comment: Run too slow for what? A lot of data may just take a lot of time to process. Correctness should be looked at first before speed. It isn't the total number of nodes that's the problem, but the longest distance from a root record to a child, and the number of parallel calls to a recursive function whose memory usage is bound to the depth of the tree. If you have no clue what kind of data you'll get, you'll need to limit the number of parallel recursive calls. If you know reasonable limits on the data, you can then optimize around that.

Comment: Also, instead of a call stack, you may want to keep your own separate stack of just the IDs of nodes leading up to the current path, so you can use an iterative solution instead. This will require a lot less stack space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have fallen pray to the temptation to write way more code than is necessary to do what you want. Given your data, we can write a simple tree structure that lets you do ancestor and descendant searching:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Node {
  // static lookup table, because we *could* try to find nodes by walking
  // the node tree, but the ids are uniquely identifying: this way we can
  // do an instant lookup. Efficiency!
  static HashMap<Long, Node> NodeLUT = new HashMap<Long, Node>();

  // we could use Node.NodeLUT.get(...), but having a Node.getNode(...) is nicer
  public static Node getNode(long id) {
    return Node.NodeLUT.get(id);
  }

  // we don't call the Node constructor directly, we just let this factory
  // take care of that for us instead.
  public static Node create(long _id, String _label) {
    return new Node(_id, _label);
  }

  public static Node create(long _id, String _label, long _parent) {
    Node parent = Node.NodeLUT.get(_parent), node;
    node = new Node(_id, _label);
    parent.addChild(node);
    return node;
  }

  // instance variables and methods

  Node parent;
  long id;
  String label;
  ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();

  // again: no public constructor. We can only use Node.create if we want
  // to make Node objects.
  private Node(long _id, String _label) {
    parent = null;
    id = _id;
    label = _label;
    Node.NodeLUT.put(id, this);
  }

  // this is taken care of in Node.create, too
  private void addChild(Node child) {
    children.add(child);
    child.setParent(this);
  }

  // as is this.
  private void setParent(Node _parent) {
    parent = _parent;
  }

  /**
   * Find the route from this node, to some descendant node with id [descendentId]
   */
  public ArrayList<Node> getDescendentPathTo(long descendentId) {
    ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>(), temp;
    list.add(this);
    if(id == descendentId) {
      return list;
    }
    for(Node n: children) {
      temp = n.getDescendentPathTo(descendentId);
      if(temp != null) {
        list.addAll(temp);
        return list;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Find the route from this node, to some ancestral node with id [descendentId]
   */
  public ArrayList<Node> getAncestorPathTo(long ancestorId) {
    ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>(), temp;
    list.add(this);
    if(id == ancestorId) {
      return list;
    }
    temp = parent.getAncestorPathTo(ancestorId);
    if(temp != null) {
      list.addAll(temp);
      return list;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "{id:"+id+",label:"+label+"}";
  }
}
```

So let's test this to make sure it works, by adding in the standard `public static void main(String[] args)` method, and for convenience, a function to turn ArrayLists of Node into something readable:

```
  public static String stringify(ArrayList<?> list) {
    String listString = "";
    for (int s=0, l=list.size(); s<l; s++) {
      listString += list.get(s).toString();
      if(s<l-1) { listString += ", "; }
    }
    return listString;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // hard coded data based on your question-supplied example data
    Node.create(0, "A");
    Node.create(1, "B", 0);
    Node.create(2, "C", 0);
    Node.create(4, "D", 1);
    Node.create(5, "E", 1);
    Node.create(6, "F", 4);
    Node.create(3, "G", 0);

    // let's see what we get!
    Node root = Node.getNode(0);
    Node f = Node.getNode(6);
    System.out.println("From root to F: " + stringify(root.getDescendentPathTo(6)));
    System.out.println("From F to root: " + stringify(f.getAncestorPathTo(0)));
  }
```

Output?

```
From root to F: {id:0,label:A}, {id:1,label:B}, {id:4,label:D}, {id:6,label:F}
From F to root: {id:6,label:F}, {id:4,label:D}, {id:1,label:B}, {id:0,label:A}
```

Perfect.

So all we need to do is write the part that turns your "flat definition" into `Node.create` calls, and done. Remember: don't over-complicate things. If your data is a flat tree, all you need is a tree structure. And all you need to write a tree structure is a single Node class.

Comment: The order of insert not always parent first and then its children, it can be randomly. So would we need a another task to link all parent of each node like LinkRecordtask above?

Comment: If you can, order the flat data so that you're always guaranteed that parent exists before the child's inserted. If that's impossible, then you can make the parent binding "late binding" by changing the `create` factory to check for `parent`, and if it doesn't exist, call a (newly defined by you) second private constructor that stores the parent's ID as `long _parentid` or something. You can then create a static `resolveParents` that can do the true crosslinking and you can call `Node.resolveParents()` once you've inserted all your nodes.

Comment: How to load all child nodes deeply of a node efficiently in case of Linear Hierarchy when you don't know the ID of the end point?

Comment: I will add one more variable in Node to reference to the deeply most child of each node. Will this is better?

Comment: you could do that, but then you'll have to update it on insert (entirely possible of course).